# Javascript Function defaulting to wrong answer (I think)

Tags: javascript, modulus

Hi can somebody tell me why the output to my function defaults to even when you insert over 17 numbers? It's probably super simple, please go easy on me!

```js
function oddOrEven(number) {
  var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
    if(number % 2 != 0) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Odd";
    } 
  
  else {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Even";
    } 
  if (number.length === 0) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Odd / Even";
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide complete code.

Comment: Your function is written with `number` as a parameter, but the first thing the function does is overwrite the parameter value. How is the function called?

Comment: Also what does "over 17 numbers" even mean? 17 numbers where?

Comment: Also, what is the typeof `number`? You check a `number.length` property which doesn't make sense if `number` is a... number.

Comment: @Tushar but that won't matter because it's used in the `%` operation only, and in fact that'd cause an error in the `.length` test.

Comment: @heylookltsme it's not  a number. It's initialized from a DOM element `.value` property, which means it's a string.

Comment: I'm guessing "over 17 numbers" means numbers with more than 17 digits, which is [above integer accuracy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin).

Comment: @danboswell when you say "17 numbers" do you mean "17 **digits**"?

Comment: If you want to test huge numbers just take a the last digit of the string and test that one.

Comment: Yes 17 digits, it looks like @JJJ might possibly have the explanation. Thank you all!

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify this whole thing.  If you are always grabbing the input with id 'number' you don't need to pass a param, and then after a simple test  you can inline the answer you want:

```
function oddOrEven(){
   var val = document.getElementById('number').value;
   var number = parseInt(val, 10);
   // if it's not a valid number, you'll have NaN here which is falsy
   if (number) {
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (number % 2) ? "Even" : "Odd";
   }
}
```

All that said, I just caught that you're talking about 17 digits (thanks to @JJJ's comment) rather than using the function more than once.  The problem in this case is that JS integers have a size limit.  If you parse anything larger it returns a number you're not going to expect.  There are a lot of discussion of general handling of very large numbers here: http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html, but for your modulus problem you could take the last digit and check if that's odd or even like so:

```
function oddOrEven(){
   var val = document.getElementById('number').value;
   var number = parseInt(val, 10);
   // if it's not a valid number, you'll have NaN here which is falsy
   if (number) {
      var lastDigit = val[val.length-1];
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (parseInt(lastDigit, 10) % 2) ? "Even" : "Odd";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It's nice to see how I can refine my code. Much appreciated!

Comment: Folks who are hitting the - button should provide comments so that I know what the issue is and can correct it.

Comment: The problem is *"my function defaults to even when you insert over 17 [digits]"* – this code has the exact same problem.

Comment: @JJJ Updated my answer to account for that, thanks for pointing it out.